# accessing value from array randomly

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.Random;


int minimum=0;
String[] code_array = new String[10];
String response= ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();
log.info(response);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("options");
Integer opt_count= jsonArray.length();
vars.put('count',Integer.toString(opt_count));
if(opt_count > 1)
{
for (int a= 0; a < opt_count; a++)
{
    code_array[a] .add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getString("code"));
    log.info(code_array[a]);
    JSONArray  new_array= jsonArray.getJSONObject(a).getJSONArray("values");
    log.info(new_array);
    int Value_count =  new_array.size();
    vars.put('VALUE_COUNT',Integer.toString(Value_count));
    if(Value_count > 1)
    {
        Random r= new Random();
        int random_value = r.nextInt(Value_count - minimum) + minimum;
        vars.put('random_value1',random_value);
        Integer FValue= 
  new_array.getJSONObject(random_value).getString("value");
        vars.put('FValue',Integer.toString(FValue));
    }
   }

}
else{

      vars.put('Attribute','First Attribute');

 }
```

JSON is herewith : [Parsing json objects(multiple) using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650288/parsing-json-objectsmultiple-using-groovy?noredirect=1#comment86311345_49650288)

i need to acheive the same : options[0].values[0].value

Above the parameter [0] on value is hardcoded. i want to randomize and get value .

Comment: and what is it you are actually having trouble with? coming up with a random index? retrieving the value?

Comment: @Stultuske both.

Comment: Any help on what part ? Can you try to read the array non randomly ? We will add the randomness on that part.

Comment: @AxelH ,  i need to achieve this in Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650288/parsing-json-objectsmultiple-using-groovy?noredirect=1#comment86311345_49650288

Comment: And ... what is the problem ? What have you tried ? What are you asking ? What are you expecting ? If you really think we are here to do your job, you didn't read the FAQ... [edit] your question with something that match the scope of SO and them I will be there to help. Right now, there is nothing but a broad requirement without an effort from you.

Comment: That's funny because in the question you asked in groovy, you said in comment "_@Jorge_B , I have written it in Java only. But i need on Groovy :) – Siddish yesterday_" so where is that Java code ?

Comment: @AxelH   Is there a way to achive  that in Java ?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do that in java. you already have it based on what you said.. or did you lied to get the groovy solution for : [Parsing json objects(multiple) using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49650288/4391450)? I am confused on your requirements and I can't help you based on what you ask. Include what you have tried first!

Comment: @AxelH , added my code.

Comment: Just use [`Random.nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) using the length of the array as an upper bound.

Comment: @AxelH dint worked

Comment: Last comment because this is taking way to much of my time... What didn't worked. You can't just say that, you need to elaborate on the incorrect behavior, what went wrong, why is it not what you expect, how you have used that, ... You clearly don't understand how that community works so I suggest you go on a [tour] of SO.

Comment: Getting error as javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method add() on null object

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your problem correctly, then you can try something like this..

```
public static int getRandomIndex(int min, int max) {

    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

}


JSONObject jsonObject1 = Array.getJSONObject(getRandomIndex(0,length_of_JSONArray));
```

Comment: Naveen , i need to do this in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650288/parsing-json-objectsmultiple-using-groovy?noredirect=1#comment86311345_49650288

Comment: This is java only!

Comment: Naveen , i need to simulate this  in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650288/parsing-json-objectsmultiple-using-groovy?noredirect=1#comment86311345_49650288

Comment: @Siddish the code Naveen presented you IS java. either his answer is correct, or your question was wrong.